# What is the number in the callstack of IntelliJ debugger?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When debugging Java code using IntelliJ, there is a number in the call stack, e.g., number "66" in the screenshot.

What is that number (66)? It is not the line number of the code (which is 52), then what is it?

[image]

Comment: It _should_ be the line number.  Is there any possibility that the version of the JAR that you're running is different from the version of the source code that the debugger has access to?

Comment: Variable names like `var7` suggest that you are looking at the output of a decompiler. The chances that a decompiler reproduces the exact source code, including having the same position of line breaks, is close to zero.